# Create metro app using existing .net4 code, that works only on x86

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have an application built in WPF. 
I want to rewrite the presentation layer to make it a metro style app.
Unfortunately I cannot do this because I cannot directly reference the business dlls in a metro style project and the metro style class library doesn't provide access to some components that I need.

Since I only want it to run on x86 anyway, is there a way to reference the other projects in the presentation so they will work directly with win32 as before and only the presentation to go through winRT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to access what you need in Win32 through the limited PInvoke support but you're most likely going to need to rewrite your library code as a Metro library to do that, rather than crossing the boundary to call your unmodified DLL on the Win32 side (which would obviously be a lot easier). You should also keep in mind that anything you do to circumvent WinRT (i.e. non-ARM supported APIs) is probably going to fail application validation and won't be able to make it into the Store.

Comment: Thanks, I have started rewriting my code since I haven't really found a way to make it work without much headache. At least this way it will work on ARM as well.

Comment: You should also check out Portable Libraries in VS2012. The more code you can put in those, the easier this kind of thing will be in the future (too bad they weren't ready a few years ago).